# SQL WITH Statement, Unknown Column in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I ve got the following query which is throwing the following error

> Unkown Column 'RowNum'

```
WITH Employees AS
(
SELECT
   (keyTblSp.RANK * 3) AS [Rank],
    sp.*,
    addr.Street,
    addr.PostOfficeBox,
    addr.StreetNumber
FROM Employee sp    
    INNER JOIN 
        FREETEXTTABLE(Employee, *, 'something', 1000) AS keyTblSp
        ON sp.EmployeeId = keyTblSp.[KEY]    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] addr ON addr.EmployeeId = sp.EmployeeId 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    (keyTblAddr.RANK * 2) AS [Rank],
    sp.*,
    addr.Street,
    addr.PostOfficeBox,
    addr.StreetNumber
FROM Employee sp    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] addr ON addr.EmployeeId = sp.EmployeeId 
    INNER JOIN 
        FREETEXTTABLE([Address], *, 'something', 1000) AS keyTblAddr
        ON addr.AddressId = keyTblAddr.[KEY]
)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Rank] DESC) AS RowNum, *
FROM Employees
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (1 - 1) * 10 + 1 AND 1 * 10
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/153598/6064933

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrpping up your query to get the name usable in the where clause

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Rank] DESC) AS RowNum
    ,   *
    FROM
        Employees) AS Results
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN (1 - 1) * 10 + 1 AND 1 * 10
ORDER BY
    Rank
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because aliases are not recognized in `WHERE` clauses. Instead, use the full query like this:

`WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Rank] DESC) BETWEEN (1 - 1) * 10 + 1 AND 1 * 10`

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` clause cannot refer to a window or aggregate function like `ROW_NUMBER()`. If you want to filter on the result of `ROW_NUMBER()`, you need to do so in the `HAVING` clause:

```
...
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Rank] DESC) AS RowNum, *
FROM Employees
HAVING RowNum BETWEEN (1 - 1) * 10 + 1 AND 1 * 10    
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

select top 10 *
from Employees
order by Rank Desc

Alternatively, does it work without the where rownum clause.  (why is your between so tricky?).