# Select AS not working in interbase

Tags: sql, delphi, interbase

works

```
select payeeid, EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM checkdate) as DOW, 
(bankcleared - checkdate) as DateDiff  
from Master  
where (bankcleared is not null)  
order by payeeid, DOW, DateDiff
```

adding `DateDiff` to `Where` - does not work

```
select payeeid, EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM checkdate) as DOW, 
(bankcleared - checkdate) as DateDiff  
from Master  
where (bankcleared is not null)  AND (DateDiff >= 1)  
order by payeeid, DOW, DateDiff
```

Comment: sorry, i also meant to ask....why adding DateDiff to where causes an error - DateDiff Column unknown

Comment: Because DATEDIFF is a built-in function, which retrieves the date part difference between two date time stamps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

Try this

```
select payeeid, EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM checkdate) as DOW, 
(bankcleared - checkdate) as DateDiff
from Master
where (bankcleared is not null) AND ((bankcleared - checkdate)>= 1)
order by payeeid, DOW, DateDiff
```

For more info go through these links

[Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

[Unknown Column In Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
select payeeid, 
       EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM checkdate) as DOW, 
       (bankcleared - checkdate) as DateDiff
from Master
WHERE (bankcleared is not null) 
AND   ((bankcleared - checkdate)>= 1)
Order by  payeeid, DOW, DateDiff
```