# Subquery field in Like

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1054, sql-like

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
(...),
(SELECT us.short FROM url_short us WHERE us.urlId = u.id
  ORDER BY us.id DESC LIMIT 1) as short, 
(...),
(SELECT f.name FROM `group` f LEFT JOIN group_url fu ON f.id = fu.group_id WHERE
  fu.url_id = u.id ORDER BY f.id DESC LIMIT 1) as f_name
FROM (...)
WHERE (...) AND
(u.url LIKE '%ops%'
OR short LIKE '%ops%'
OR u.url_name LIKE '%ops%'
OR f_name LIKE '%ops%')
(...)
```

However, when I try to use LIKE in `short` and `f_group` MySQL say me that:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'short' in 'where clause'`

I already search a lot and found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use alias in your query, and this probably causes this error.
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause) another question with similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

your where clause does not see the `short` alias as it is only introduced through the projection step taking place *after* the filtering of the result set (which is realized by the outermost `WHERE` clause).

try

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
          SELECT
          (...),
          (SELECT us.short FROM url_short us WHERE us.urlId = u.id
            ORDER BY us.id DESC LIMIT 1) as short, 
          (...),
          (SELECT f.name FROM `group` f LEFT JOIN group_url fu ON f.id = fu.group_id WHERE
            fu.url_id = u.id ORDER BY f.id DESC LIMIT 1) as f_name
          FROM (...)
          WHERE (...)
       ) emb
   WHERE (emb.url LIKE '%ops%'
          OR emb.short LIKE '%ops%'
          OR emb.url_name LIKE '%ops%'
          OR emb.f_name LIKE '%ops%')
       ;
```

Comment: Great idea friend, however I'll stay with Having, that Iwo had suggested 'cause it's faster and I need it to be fast.
Thank you anyway, it's a good idea.