# SELECT cols, (SELECT inner query) AS innercol FROM table WHERE innercol something

Tags: mysql

It works as long as I avoid the `WHERE stream_json ...` can this be fixed or does it require JOINS?

```
SELECT id, stuff,
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM inner_table
     WHERE inner_table.movie_id = outer_table.id) 
          AS stream_json
FROM outer_table 
WHERE stream_json != 0
```

Comment: What exactly your question is ?

Comment: @dianuj can this be fixed or does it require JOINS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` to access the custom aliases they cannot be entertained using `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM inner_table
WHERE inner_table.movie_id = outer_table.id) AS stream_json
FROM outer_table HAVING stream_json != 0
```

[**See this for reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause/17953521)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aliases in WHERE conditions. However, you can use it in HAVING conditions. Another choice is to repeat whole subquery but that looks ugly. I recommend using HAVING.

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM inner_table
WHERE inner_table.movie_id = outer_table.id) AS stream_json
FROM outer_table HAVING stream_json != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As above you can use HAVING, or you can join against a subselect which avoid the correlated subquery

```
SELECT outer_table.id, outer_table.stuff, stream_json
FROM outer_table 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT movie_id, count(*) AS stream_json
    FROM inner_table
    GROUP BY movie_id
) Sub1
ON Sub1.movie_id = outer_table.id
```

Note that you do not need the check for stream_json != 0 for this as it is implicit in the INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the column alias on the same level. You need to wrap that into a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT id, 
         stuff,
         (SELECT count(*) 
          FROM inner_table
          WHERE inner_table.movie_id = outer_table.id) AS stream_json
  FROM outer_table
) t  
WHERE stream_json <> 0;
```

But Kickstart's answer is probably the better solution to this problem.