# unknow column in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a query like this -

```
SELECT e.id, 
       ( (SELECT ABS((SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(ud.dob) 
                      FROM   user_detail ud 
                      WHERE  ud.userid = 49) - AVG(avgr.abc 
                                                   + (SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(ud.dob) 
                                                      FROM   user_detail ud 
                                                      WHERE  ud.userid = 49))) AS VALUE 
          FROM   (SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(ud.dob) AS abc 
                  FROM   user_detail ud 
                  WHERE  ud.userid = (SELECT ei.interested_user 
                                      FROM   event_interest ei 
                                      WHERE  ei.eventid = e.id 
                                             AND ei.approvalstatus = 'Approve') 
                  UNION 
                  SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(ud.dob) AS abc 
                  FROM   user_detail ud 
                  WHERE  ud.userid = (SELECT ei.invited_user 
                                      FROM   event_invite ei 
                                      WHERE  ei.eventid = e.id 
                                             AND ei.acceptance = 'Accept')) AS avgr) 
         + (SELECT IFNULL(( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(22.6979425)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(75.8597305)) + SIN(RADIANS(22.6979425)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude))) ), 0)
            FROM   address a 
            WHERE  a.latitude != '' 
                   AND a.longitude != '' 
                   AND e.event_address = a.id) ) AS dest 
FROM   event e 
WHERE  ( ( e.maximumattendeesallow > ( (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
                                        FROM   event_interest 
                                        WHERE  eventid = e.id 
                                               AND approvalstatus = 'Approve') 
                                       + (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
                                          FROM   event_invite 
                                          WHERE  eventid = e.id 
                                                 AND acceptance = 'Accept') ) ) 
          OR ( e.maximumattendeesallow = 0 ) ) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT id 
                   FROM   address a 
                   WHERE  latitude != '' 
                          AND longitude != '' 
                          AND e.event_address = id 
                          AND IFNULL(( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(22.6979425)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(75.8597305)) + SIN(RADIANS(22.6979425)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude))) ), 0) < 100)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT eventid 
                       FROM   event_interest 
                       WHERE  e.id = eventid 
                              AND approvalstatus != 'InterestExpressed' 
                              AND interested_user = 49) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT eventid 
                       FROM   event_invite 
                       WHERE  eventid = e.id 
                              AND invited_user = 49);
```

This query giving me error -

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'e.id' in 'where clause'
```

Why its not allowing subquery to use e.id in order by clause.

Comment: Please format your query.

Comment: I have seen this post -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause
which says where clause e.id first evaluate, how i can rewrite this query so later one evaluate first.

Answer (score 0):

In the query, you have used **E.ID**. change it to "**e.id**" and execute. This time you won't get that error.

Comment: Please consodilate and remove one of your answers

Answer (score 0):

In fourth select clause, that is after AND NOT EXISTS(Select..,  . In where clause you mentioned as **WHERE e.id =eventid** , instead of this , write as **WHERE eventid = e.id** . This will resolve your error.