# Spring Query: Haversine formula with pageable

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, haversine

I'm trying to use the [Haversine formula](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql) to find entities near to a location in a [Spring Data JPA Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html) with [Pageable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) but I dont get it done.

My first approach looks like this

```
    @Query("SELECT m, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(m.latitude)) * cos(radians(m.longitude) - radians(:longitude)) + sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(m.latitude)))) as dist FROM Entity m WHERE dist < :distance ORDER BY dist DESC")
    public List<Entity> findEntitiesByLocation(@Param("latitude") final double latitude, @Param("longitude") final double longitude, @Param("distance") final double distance, Pageable pageable);
```

but it fails as Spring/JPA seems to be not capable of using aliases in the where clause. The SQL in the stacktrace looks like this

```
select (...),(haversine) as col_1_0_ where dist<? order by col_1_0_ DESC
```

so the alias in the where clause is not replaced. Using "col_1_0_" (without the ") instead of dist also does not work.

According to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153641/1089459), at least MySQL is interpreted inside out and using aliases in the Where clause is not possible. A suggested solution would be using HAVING instead of WHERE, but also in a HAVING clause, the alias is not resolved.

I know that I can move the Haversine Formula into the where clause, but I still need it in the Order By clause and I think it might slow down performance using the same long Haversine formula in the Order By clause as I select from a few hundred thousands entities.

I then tried to create the Query manually but I don't know how to apply the Pageable to this:

```
    @Override
    public List<Entity> findEntitiesByLocation(final double latitude, final double longitude, final double distance, Pageable pageable) {
    final javax.persistence.Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_ENTITES_BY_DISTANCE);

    query.setParameter("latitude", latitude);
    query.setParameter("longitude", longitude);
    query.setParameter("distance", distance);

    final List<Entity> entities = query.getResultList();
    // order by distance
    entities .sort(new EntityDistanceComparator(latitude, longitude));

    return entities ;
}
```

So, I either need the first approach with @Query to work (which I'd prefer) OR the second approach with Pageable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With Neil Stockton's help I decided to stick with the non native query using the Haversine formula in both the WHERE and ORDER BY clause so I can still use Spring's pagination feature. My final solution looks like this:

```
static final String HAVERSINE_PART = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(m.latitude)) * cos(radians(m.longitude) - radians(:longitude)) + sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(m.latitude))))";

@Query("SELECT m FROM Entity m WHERE "+HAVERSINE_PART+" < :distance ORDER BY "+HAVERSINE_PART+" DESC")
public List<Entity> findEntitiesByLocation(@Param("latitude") final double latitude, @Param("longitude") final double longitude, @Param("distance") final double distance, Pageable pageable);
```

With 100.000 entities, this takes approximately about 585 ms to find the top 10 nearest entities to a given location and about 8s to find the top 10 nearest entities within 1.000.000 entities, which is ok for me right now. If I optimize the query, I'll post it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Shouldn't `m.latitude` changed to `e.latitude` in your example?

Answer (score 3):

JPQL doesn't allow "result aliases" in the WHERE, HAVING clauses; they can only be used in the ORDER clause. Similarly the use of RADIANS, COS, ACOS, SIN, ASIN etc is non-portable JPQL; some implementations may support them (I know DataNucleus JPA does, and looks like you have Hibernate also) but not guaranteed.

Just use a NativeQuery and push in whatever SQL you require. You lose (RDBMS) portability, but then you didn't have that with what you were attempting above (for JPA provider or RDBMS).

Comment: Thanks Neil! I wasn't aware that RADIANS, COS, ACOS... already breaks with the JPQL specification. As you suggested right I use Hibernate as a JPA provider, so the statement works so far. Right now I decided to stick with the not native Query and use the Haversine formula in the WHERE and ORDER clause cause with a native query I would loose Spring's pagination feature. I tested performance on 100.000 Entities which was ok so far.