# Is there a way I can essentially pass values sent from client side to local variables for an sql query in spring?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I'm currently working on a web app that will rate neighbourhoods on a number of different criteria, one of which being statistics from the local Garda station (police station in Irish). I'm passing a latitude and longitude value from the client side into a controller in Spring and I want to run the following SQL query so I can find the nearest police station and return the relevant statistics.

```
Set @lat = x; // Local Variable for a latitude value
Set @lng = y; // Local Variable for a longitude value

SELECT * FROM garda_station
ORDER BY ((garda_station_latitude - @lat)*
         (garda_station_latitude - @lat))+
         ((garda_station_longitude - @lng)*
         (garda_station_longitude - @lng))
ASC LIMIT 1;
```

The garda_station table I'm trying to access is structured as follows

```
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| garda_station_id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| garda_station_latitude  | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| garda_station_longitude | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| garda_station_name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm passing the latitude & longitude values from the client side via an AJAX request to a Controller class in my Spring project.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String Submit(@RequestParam("latitude") String latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") String longitude) {
    // I'm printing them for now to ensure they have been sent from the client side
    System.out.println(latitude + "" + longitude);
    return "/";
}
```

This is my first big attempt at a spring project so if there were any other suggestions as to how I could conduct this SQL query I'd love to heat your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use JDBCTemplate (see [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) and [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jdbc/spring-jdbctemplate-example/)). But actually it would be better to define a stored procedure to calculate disctance and use the procedure (see [here](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/mysql-calculating-distance-based-on-latitude-and-longitude.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would your opinion be of using a JPA query method through the Repository class, something like this, `public GardaStation findByGardaStation_LatitudeAndGardaStation_Longitude(double latitude, double longitude);`, with the possibility of a customised query to this if possible?

Comment: That's fine for me. Originally you asked without JPA/Spring data. That's why I suggested JDBCTemplate based approach. You actual query is not perfect. It's better to use more complicated formula. In opposite case result precision strongly depends on latitude.

Comment: Apologies I should've specified I meant JPA/Spring data. Would you know of a resource I could look at that would help me to create a customised JPA Query based on an SQL statement?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576674/spring-query-haversine-formula-with-pageable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966967/creating-a-custom-query-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Thank you. Top answer for your help.