# PHP / SQL, simple select where get the "value" as column

Tags: php, mysql

```
$account = "proot"; 

        $sql_check_account = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = $account");

    if(!$sql_check_account)
            die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

Return :

Unknown column 'proot' in 'where clause'

Same with :

```
 $sql_check_account = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = "'.$account.'"');
```

Or

```
 $sql_check_account = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username =".$account);
```

What can make the variable $account perform as a column ? I don't get the problem here...

Thanks !

Comment: try enclosing proot_accounts in backticks ie "`"

Comment: your 2nd example should work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, same error with the backticks and second example won't work :(

Comment: Backticks are for mysql column/table names. You are trying to compare a `VARCHAR` value. See my answer below.

Comment: does your `$account` have a quote in it `'`/`"`?

Comment: Maybe this thread would be useful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause. I've never seen this before, is there an error code with this error?

Comment: Thanks chris, already read this topic before to post this one :(

Comment: What about `"SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = (select '$account';)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around it.

```
mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = '$account'");
```

You should also explore prepared SQL statements in PHP. They will save a lot of these formatting headaches.

Comment: how is this different than the OPs 2nd example?

Comment: This is different because it generates a SQL statement with quotation marks in it. You want `username = "value"` and not `username = value`

Comment: Are you still getting `Unknown column 'proot' in 'where clause'`? Echo the query you are generating and share the result.

Comment: there : Unknown column 'proot' in 'where clause'

Comment: this is does not create a statement different than the OPs `'SELECT ... WHERE username = "'.$account.'"'`

Comment: It looks like it does make the SQL string have single quotes around `$account` instead of double quotes.

Comment: @Don'tPanic although MySQL runs the same with single or double quotes

Comment: Single or double quotes shouldn't matter. But if MySQL is thinking 'proot' is a column that means the quotes must not be going through. @Anyone_ph, can you alter your program to print the query instead of running it?

Comment: @Sean, Doesn't that depend on the server mode? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Comment: Can you run this? `echo 'SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = "'.$account.'"'`

Comment: php register.php (CLI)->
SELECT username FROM proot_accounts  WHERE username = "proot"
With my on my example
SELECT username FROM proot_accounts  WHERE username = proot

Comment: So you see how in the first one you get the quotes and the second you don't? Try sending the quoted one to MySQL.

Comment: Yep I rewrite the script with your quote example, works thanks for your time !

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a quoting issue. This:

```
"SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = $account"
```

will get you this string:

> SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = proot

In this case MySQL is thinking proot is a column name, because proot is not in quotes at all.

This:

```
'SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = "'.$account.'"'
```

will get you this string:

> SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = "proot"

In this case, MySQL may still think "proot" is a column name, depending on the SQL mode. Since you are still getting the same error when you use this code, it looks like your database is set to [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) mode. In this mode, text inside quotation marks will be interpreted as an column identifier, not a literal value.

Using this:

```
"SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = '$account'"
```

will get you this string:

> SELECT username FROM proot_accounts WHERE username = 'proot'

Using `'` instead of `"` should ensure that MySQL will treat `proot` like a literal value instead of a column identifier regardless of the SQL mode.