# Column alias not usable in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I've written a php script that builds a query based on a keyword/select menu search system. The script works great right up until I try searching on a column alias:

```
SELECT
    contacts.*,
    orders.order_id AS is_customer,
    purchases.purchase_id AS is_supplier
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id=contacts.contact_id
LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.supplier_id=contacts.contact_id
WHERE is_customer IS NOT NULL
AND contacts.account_id=1
GROUP BY contact_id
ORDER BY contact_company_name
```

It's the line `WHERE is_customer IS NOT NULL` that's the problem - MySQL tells me it doesn't exist. I understand why this is so but that doesn't help me.

I have tried changing it to `HAVING is_customer IS NOT NULL` based on a tip I read here [Unknown Column In Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause), thus:

```
SELECT
    contacts.*,
    orders.order_id AS is_customer,
    purchases.purchase_id AS is_supplier
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id=contacts.contact_id
LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.supplier_id=contacts.contact_id
HAVING is_customer IS NOT NULL
AND contacts.account_id=1
ORDER BY contact_company_name
```

...and this query works just fine providing I remove the `GROUP BY` clause. Obviously this breaks my result set.

Can anyone help me polish off this query please?

Comment: I don't see any aggregations so placing WHERE orders.order_id is not null would work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's generally done to answer your own question but I've got it working by having a read of this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html.

Turns out the statement worked with the `GROUP BY` just fine, I simply needed to rearrange the order of the statement. The `GROUP BY` comes after the `WHERE` but before the `HAVING`, like so:

```
SELECT
    contacts.*,
    orders.order_id AS is_customer,
    purchases.purchase_id AS is_supplier
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id=contacts.contact_id
LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.supplier_id=contacts.contact_id
AND contacts.account_id=1
GROUP BY contact_id
HAVING is_supplier IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY contact_company_name
```