# Pdo query exception on M2ePro frensh install

Tags: php, mysql, magento, m2e-pro

We have installed a new Magento 1.9.2.1 install with M2ePro 6.3.6 release with no custom so far.
When we click on M2ePro menu options we get following error locate on Pdo.php:

````
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`group`' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `m2epro_primary_config` AS `main_table` WHERE (```group``` = '/modules/') AND (```key``` = 'm2epro')
````

The error is on a query generated by Magento, it is not a human generated query.

Here column group et key contain too many quotes, don't understand why.

Any idea ? config related ?

Comment: I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. It means there is no column called ` `group` `. You likely need to remove those extra backticks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown Column In Where Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause)

Comment: As a side note, it's generally not a good idea to use reserved words for column or table names.

Answer (score 1):

Have you patched Magento with the SUPEE-6788 patch? If so M2EPro 6.3.6 is not compatible, upgrade to 6.3.8. The backticks are a "feature" that has been disallowed in Magento with the SUPEE-6788 patch due to the security issues arising from previously allowing them.

Comment: Yes, following the issue with M2ePro team, they relased a new version 6.3.8, that solved the pb. Thanks!